# I have swagger URL to TEST IN jmeter but not getting proper response

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have swagger URL to test in JMeter: http://192.168.1.185:9100/swagger-ui.html#/bd-config-controller/getUsingGET
when I break this URL into IP:192.168.1.185
                           port:9100
                           path:/swagger-ui.html#/bd-config-controller/getUsingGET
I am getting this response in GET request which I am not able to understand. Although the get has only STRING{id}: 
Response in results tree is: !-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->



  
  Swagger UI
  
  
  
  
  
    html
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after
    {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

```
body {
  margin:0;
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
  <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
  <path d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
  <path d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
  <path d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z"/>
</symbol>


<symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
  <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
  <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"/>
</symbol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm under impression you're doing the wrong thing, you should not be testing [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) itself, my expectation is that you need to test the [REST API endpoint instead](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/), Swagger UI can only be used for examining and playing with the APIs.

You may find [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool useful, it comes with [`swagger2yaml` utility](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/#swagger2yaml-Convert-Swagger-specs-into-Taurus-YAML) which can convert Swagger UI definitions into [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) config script and once you get the YAML file you can easily get a JMeter test plan from it by running the following command:

```
bzt your_file.yaml -gui
```

This command will open JMeter GUI with the test plan loaded so you will be able to save it as normal JMeter .jmx script.

Check out [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/) article for more information

Comment: Sorry, Dmitri for asking such a silly question. I Have examined the endpoints but the project is based on a microservices architecture i.e. the JWT token or authorization changes severely whenever someone logged on the server so what token I have extracted from the USER CONTROLLER(Authentication API) when I am passing that token on further requests it is showing error 401 or authorization failed. SO what should I do to configure some request sampler that every time when test runs it fetches the current JWT TOKEN. and test run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If what Dmitri stated is the case, you can simply take the swagger specification file and generate JMeter test scripts using OpenAPI Generator.

[https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation/]

There are several options for installing OpenAPI Generator but the easiest I found to deal with behind a bunch of company restrictions, is the jar.

Then just run this command and they will generate: java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i swaggerSpec.json -g jmeter